# why this search function in list doesn't work?

Tags: c, linked-list

I made this easy linked list and i would like to add element in it checking if the element is already present.

If the new element to add is already present, the node won't be inserted in the list.

Well, the problem begins when a insert the second element; gdb says:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555554bda in search (name=0x5555557576d0 "alfred")
at Scrivania/test.c:*line*
*line*      while(strncmp(name,temp->name,strlen(name))!=0)
```

Code:

```
typedef struct node{
    char *name;
    struct node *n;
} N;

N *h = NULL;

void insert(char *name){
    N *temp = malloc(sizeof(N));
    if (h == NULL){
        h=temp;
        temp->n = NULL;
        temp->name = strdup(name);
    } else {
        N *curr = h;
        while (curr->n != NULL)
            curr = curr->n;
        curr->n = temp;
        temp->name = strdup(name);
    }
}

N *search(char *name) {
    N *temp = h;
    if (temp == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else{
        while (strncmp(name, temp->name, strlen(name)) != 0)
            temp=temp->n;        
        return temp;
    }
}

int main() {
    char *name = N * temp=search(name); //getting input
    if (temp == NULL) 
        insert(name);
    //these four lines sequence repeat for every input
}
```

Comment: Where does your input come from?  Is it read from a file, is it entered via user input (`sdtin`)?...

Comment: In the search function is the name is not found you will go off the end of the list and crash.  You need to check for temp != NULL in the while condition.

Comment: In addition to @jmq 's comment, by using `strncmp`, you are not checking if the strings are identical, but if the start of `temp->name` contains `name`.  if `temp->name` = "abcd" and `name` = "a", then it will return as a match.

Comment: Reformatted code

Comment: `while (curr->n != NULL)` should be `while (curr != NULL)`. Don't `malloc` until you know you will insert (not a duplicate) OR make sure you `free()` if it is. Otherwise you create a memory leak for every duplicate you attempt to insert.